# How do I remove app from 3rd party website?

Tags: android, apk

I noticed my android app apk is appearing on https://apkpremier.com/

Is there anyway to prevent the app from being listed there?

Comment: You can't make an apk that can't be uploaded to 3rd party sites so try to contact them: https://apkpremier.com/aboutus/dmca has an address

Answer (score 0):

Ask google to remove:
[legal assistance google](https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=in-EU)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).